# Disable button if a specific column has a certain value

Tags: javascript, php, html

So what I'm currently trying to do know is if a column has a value of "TO BE CHECK" the "Print" button will be disabled.

Can someone help me with this?

**Code is attached below.**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <table id="MyTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Food Lane Sticker Control Number</th>
      <th scope="col">OR/CR #</th>
      <th scope="col">Business Permit #</th>
      <th scope="col" id="test">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody name="MyTable" id="tbody">
    <tr name="MyTable">
      <th name="MyTable"></th>
      <th name="MyTable"></th>
      <th name="MyTable"></th>
      <th name="MyTable">TO BE CHECK</th>
      <td name="MyTable">

      <button type="submit" id="print" name="print" class="btn btn-success">Print</button>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery, you could do

```
$('#MyTable th[name="MyTable"], #MyTable td[name="MyTable"]').each( function(i,e){

  if (e.innerHTML === "TO BE CHECK") {

    $('#Print').prop('disabled', true);
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

disabled  onclick="addtocart()" />

Comment: <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" <?php if ($prod_qty == '0'){ ?> disabled <?php   } ?> onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $row["prod_id"]?>)" />